# creating my own Word wrapper for string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

How do I make my own word wrap function for strings?  I want each line to be no longer than 50 characters and respect existing CRLFs.

Comment: Do you mean every 50 characters you want to add a newline if there is not one already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, it will get you started (just a quick samle i mashed together):

```
Private Sub Doit()     
    Dim Source As String = ""
    Source &= "How to make my own word wrap function for string, I want each line to be no longer than 50chars and take respect existing CRLFs" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Source &= "So this will be a new row."
    Dim wrappedtext As String = wrap(Source, 20, vbNewLine)
    MsgBox(wrappedtext)
End Sub

Function wrap(ByVal text As String, ByVal maxlength As Integer, ByVal newline As String) As String

    Dim tmp() As String = Split(text.Replace(vbCrLf, " | "), " ")
    Dim ret As String = ""
    Dim wrk As String = ""
    For Each word As String In tmp
        If word = "|" Then
            ret &= newline
            wrk = ""
        ElseIf word = "" Then

        Else

            If Len(wrk & word) <= maxlength Then
                wrk &= " " & word
            Else
                ret &= wrk & newline
                wrk = word & " "
            End If

        End If
    Next
    If wrk <> "" Then ret &= wrk
    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, nice code, but sometimes leaves words from the middle ! also has double spaces time to time.

Comment: Yes. I just throwed it together so its just a "prototype". But it should not be a hard task to fix it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

From which point of view? SW architecture?

Take a look at the decorator pattern. If you like to work with streams, in the book "Heads First: Design Patterns" a string modifier is proposed. It's in Java, but the general programming concept is described in a good way. Some pages are missing but you can find many infos [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&dq=heads+first+design+pattern&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=de&ei=R0auSq_vIoPW-QbA_tCsBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

The algorithm itself is trivial, isn't it?